# How do I run fckeditor?

Tags: software-installation

I installed fckeditor by using Ubuntu Software Center successfully. But I do not know how can I run it. The Ubuntu menu does not seem to contain any link which refers to it. Where is it located?

Comment: which version of Ubuntu do you have installed?

Comment: @Kory Wnuk 10.04 LTS

Comment: It looks like fckeditor is not what you think it is.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=794225

Comment: @Jason Iverson I think you are right. Thank you. Post your comment as a answer in order to mark as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like fckeditor is not what you think it is:

> fckeditor is a web text editor. It will not have a binary as it's just javascript. I might be mistaken but I think you're supposed to use it with Drupal or something similar.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=794225